# Magento > Tools > Backup Issue

Tags: magento-1.8

On visiting System>Tools>Backup link, Magento system give me below error

```
Item (Varien_Object) with the same id "0_db" already exist
```

Trace

```
#0 /home/sanasana/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Filesystem.php(307): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Varien_Object))
#1 /home/sanasana/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(622): Varien_Data_Collection_Filesystem->loadData(false, false)
#2 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(533): Varien_Data_Collection->load()
#3 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Backup/Grid.php(51): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#4 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Backup_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#5 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#6 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#7 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('backupsGrid', true)
#9 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Backup.php(104): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('backupsGrid')
#10 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/list.phtml(39): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Backup->getGridHtml()
#11 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/sanasana/...')
#12 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#13 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#18 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#20 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#21 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/sanasana/...')
#22 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#23 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#24 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#28 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/BackupController.php(56): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#29 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_BackupController->indexAction()
#30 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#31 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#32 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#33 /home/sanasana/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#34 /home/sanasana/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#35 {main}
```

I am not sure what to do, I have tried to google it but found us very less result.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I don't suspect this is a resolution as such but perhaps a workaround for now...

Open up `/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php`

Find the following function:-

```
public function addItem(Varien_Object $item)
{
    $itemId = $this->_getItemId($item);

    if (!is_null($itemId)) {
        if (isset($this->_items[$itemId])) {
            throw new Exception('Item ('.get_class($item).') with the same id "'.$item->getId().'" already exist');
        }
        $this->_items[$itemId] = $item;
    } else {
        $this->_addItem($item);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

And comment out the following line:-

```
throw new Exception('Item ('.get_class($item).') with the same id "'.$item->getId().'" already exist');
```

Resulting in:-

```
public function addItem(Varien_Object $item)
{
    $itemId = $this->_getItemId($item);

    if (!is_null($itemId)) {
        if (isset($this->_items[$itemId])) {
            //throw new Exception('Item ('.get_class($item).') with the same id "'.$item->getId().'" already exist');
        }
        $this->_items[$itemId] = $item;
    } else {
        $this->_addItem($item);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

See if that then allows you to access `System > Tools > Backup`.

Answer (score 1):

Tiny bit late for an answer, but I just found its because there was a corrupted backup file in the httpdocs/var/backups/ folder. Manually remove all the backup files in this folder and see if that fixes it.